# Files app (com.android.documentsui) crashes on Recent tab

Tags: file-management, system-apps

I have a Xiaomi Redmi Note 7 with Android 9. There's this factory app called "**Files**" (which is **com.android.documentsui**) that's not working properly anymore.

I have some apps on my phone like AutomaTag to change the tags of my songs and Sticker Maker to make WhatsApp Stickers. Both of them use this Files app when I have to select an image. Unfortunately, the app is not opening, and when it's opening, it just crashes or doesn't respond at all after a few seconds.

I tried deleting data for that Files app and for both my apps, but it didn't work. So, the next thing I did was installing an app that created a shortcut to that Files app, and surprisingly, it opened and worked! Slow, but it worked, except when I try to open the "Recent" tab, that one crashes the app.

Okay, that's fine, so I just have to avoid that Recent thing. Except, *every time "Files" opens, it opens on that Recent thing, so it crashes every time.*

I also deleted the cache and when I open the app, it worked. But when I tried to select something, it crashed again.

What do I have to do? Can I delete that app? And how do I do it? Do I need to replace it?

Comment: Connect your phone via `adb` with a PC and start `adb logcat`. Usually if an app crashes there is an error message and a stack trace in the logcat output. Without the error message and the stack trace we can only guess the problem source. Additionally with that stack trace you could open an issue ticket at Xiaomi and/or Google if it is a general bug of the app.

Comment: Or just use another file explorer - many on Play Store. Solid Explorer is a good choice. Mixplorer from XDA is great

Answer (score 0):

Enable Developer options. Go into Developer options > Running services > Cached processes. Stop  all Google service or process you see there.